# mysql_real_escape_string problem?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the first time this has ever happened, and its really weird.

We have been using this function for years, and we are using it everywhere on this site.. although one particilar part of the site - it is causing mySQL errors.

```
function noescape($str) {
$noescape = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
return $noescape;
}

$email = noescape($_POST['email']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `contact` (`email`) VALUES('" . $email . "') ", $database) or die(mysql_error());
```

Yes, `$database` is defined and it is the right connection info - it is used in other areas of the site.

Error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be
>   established in /home/user/public_html/config.php on line 27

Infact, the error happens on this line:

```
$email = noescape($_POST['email']);
```

It is nothing to do with the query.

I found this: http://www.resourcebookingpro.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=66&func=view&catid=3&id=841#844

What is wrong??

Comment: Are you calling noescape() from elsewhere, from before the database connection is established? Because `If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING`

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` relies on getting locale information from the server -- it is trying to get it, and failing. I would recommend ditching it and using placeholders if possible (mysqli or PDO work just fine). It will solve this problem (both of them).

Comment: Why are you making a function that does practically nothing? you might as well have used `mysql_real_escape_string()` and that's it.

Comment: @Rik because its faster to type.

Comment: @Kyle R And it's even faster and cleaner (and more consistent) to use placeholders... ditch manually creating SQL strings except in very tricky cases like dynamic generation (and even then, *use placeholders*).

Comment: Can you show how you are connecting to the database?

Comment: @Kyle no, PDO is faster to type and cleaner to use placeholders. This is unnecessary extra functions.

Comment: Can you show how you are connecting to the database?

Answer (score 1):

> Things above this in the page are using the same connection and it is working fine...

Well, you have to check the code above this line to see where connection gets closed.

Answer (score -2):

I think you must  specified mysql link correctly (as said in comments)

```
function noescape($str) {
global  $database;
$noescape = mysql_real_escape_string($str, $database);
return $noescape;
}

$email = noescape($_POST['email']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `contact` (`email`) VALUES('" . $email . "') ", $database) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @user `If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.`

Comment: And.. mysql_connect without arguments try to create connection with default args which was declared in the php directive mysql.defaulthost etc... And this connection throw warning. Why not

Comment: @user the OP states that he has a database connection already established. The escape string function should not have this error. Finding out why that suddently stopped working should be the 1st priority

Comment: if you see all logs than you'll see that I am right. PHP try to create default connection (through default socket if 'localhost' is default mysql server) and can't do it and generate warning than bad connection given to mysql_real_escape_string() and we have that we have - warning.

Comment: @user yes, but the OP is stating **he has a database connection already established.** He claims that the subsequent `mysql_query()` goes through without problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3120/discussion-between-user900898-and-pekka)

Answer (score -2):

The real escape string method does rely on db connection. I believe $database is global to the application, so simply put a if statement in noescape method to test if its null like so:

```
if($database)
{
  $noescape = mysql_real_escape_string($str, $database);
  return $noescape;
}
```

I agree with everyone else's thoughts; but I do think you should check for null.

Good luck

Comment: Shouldn't it use a previously open connection? Things above this in the page are using the same connection and it is working fine...

Comment: @Kyle yes, it should. so, you have to open it first